# Creating variable via *ngIf in Angular

Tags: angular

I use Angular 10 and the `*ngIf` directive to create a variable in my HTML template as in the code below:

```
<div *ngIf="function() as foo">
    <p>Header</p>
    <div *ngFor="let x of foo">
    ....
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let y of foo">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason why I don't call `function()` in `*ngFor` directly is the fact that I use the array `foo` in several other areas of the template and the function is very cost intensive.

My problem is now, if `function` returns an empty array, the entire template is rendered empty - including the `<p>` directive

Is there any way how I can still render the container, although `files` is empty? I tried the code below but that seems to be an invalid syntax:

```
*ngIf="(function() as foo) || true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally what you'd be looking for here is `*ngLet`, but that has [not yet been implemented](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280). But you can find various third party libraries that provide such a directive. However, Igor Minar, an Angular core team member, [has stated](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280#issuecomment-430479166) that for performance these are not great (but certainly usable for now), since they're forced to rely on `createEmbeddedView`, which is rather expensive for this.

The better answer would be to save the outcome of the function in a class member. Especially so if the function is expensive to run as due to change detection even if you did the above, it would still run fairly often (unless you take very specific control over the change detection yourself). That way you can fully control how often and when the function is evaluated.

An easy trick is to add a console log to your function and watch how often it gets called. When running in development mode it'll even always be called twice on each run since Angular does that to find bugs in your application.

TL;DR Calling (expensive) functions from the template is simply not a good idea in Angular.